Object property type narrowing: dot vs object literal?
I noticed that type narrowing by assignment works differently depending on what syntax we are using: dot notation or object literal notation. Why is that? Here are two examples.
type MyObj = { x?: number | string }

let obj1: MyObj = {}
obj1.x = 1 // assign x with dot
obj1.x // number

let obj2: MyObj;
obj2 = { x: 1 }; // assign x with object literal
obj2.x // number | string | undefind

I expected the same behaviour in both of those cases.

Narrowing happens only on the union.
In your first example, you assign to a property x directly, which is of a union type number | string | undefined so the control flow narrows it down to number for the rest of the scope. But in your second example, you assign to an object that is not a union, so the control flow won't narrow it.
The narrowing also happens only in the current scope, you will loose it in a nested function for example.
I get you, it seems like TS could figure it out, but sadly it doesn't, at least for now, they constantly improve control flow analysis.
If you change your type to a union then assigning a literal object will narrow it:
type MyObj = { x?: number | string }

let obj1: MyObj = {}
obj1.x = 1 // assign x with dot
obj1.x // number

function anotherScope() {
    obj1.x // number | string | undefind
}

let obj2: MyObj;
obj2 = { x: 1 }; // assign x with object literal
obj2.x // number | string | undefind

obj2.x = 2;
obj2.x // number

let obj3: { x: number  } | { x: string } | { x?: undefined };
obj3 = { x: 1 } ; // assign x with object literal
obj3.x // number, narrowed to first member of the union


let obj4: { x?: number  } | { x?: string } 
obj4 = { x: 1 } ; // assign x with object literal
obj4.x // number | undefind, narrowed to first member of the union


Playground
These are the related issues where it is mentioned that the above is a design limitation in TypeScript.
1.
2.
